# Python printing the first item of each nested list with a single print command

Tags: python, list, nested, items

I would like to know why does this code does not output the first item of each nested list.
I have found an alternative that works but I would like to know why this one does not output the desired output.

```
tableData = [
['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'], 
['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]
print(tableData[:][1])
```

Comment: `print(list(zip(*tableData))[0])` would print all first elelents

Comment: Why do you think that slicing notation would also cause iteration as a side effect?

Answer (score 1):

`tableData[:]` returns the entire list. So `tableData[:][1]` only returns the second element in `tableData`, which is your list `['Alice', 'Bob', ...]`.

You can get the first element of every list using a list comprehension:

```
print [sublist[0] for sublist in tableData]
```

The above code is equivalent to this:

```
first_elements = []
for sublist in tableData:
    first_elements.append(sublist[0])
print first_elements
```

Comment: I found a solution, but I want to know why my code does not work as I think it is intended to.

Comment: @MehdiRezzagHebla in numpy/pandas your syntax is the right idea, but like `tableData[:,1]`

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work because `tableData[:]` returns the whole list. It's an equivalent of `tableData` (without `[:]`). As posted Josh, you can use a list comprehension to get the elements you want.

Comment: yes but I added a second pair of square brackets to specify what I need from the whole list.

Answer (score 1):

Because `tableData[:]` means the whole list, which is just a copy of `tableData`. So `tableData[:][1]` is the 1-th (second) item in `tableData`, which is `['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David']` in your code.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `[0]` this will get the first element in the list then you do a for loop to go through every element in the list for example:

```
tableData = [
['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'], 
['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]
for i in tableData:
    print(i[0])
```

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
print([i[0] for i in tableData])
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the code for this
which gives clean space seperated output
`print(*[i[0] for i in tableData])`
In Your the tableData[:] will evaluate to TableData then TableData[1] will evaluate to ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David']

Answer (score 0):

`[ from: to]` operator means slicing - > returns new string.

For example:

```
lst = [0, 1, 2, 3] 
lst[0:2] #will return [0, 1]
```

[ : ] will return the list as it is.

So if you want to access the first value type:
lst[0]
 In your code you typed tableData[1] so it returns the second index because the indexes starts from Zero